# Swing component to open an existing file and then after viewing file save the file

Tags: swing

I need a swing component for opening an existing CSV file in notepad or respective available viewer installed on machine and then after viewing give the capability to the user to save the file.

Appreciate your help.

Regards
Paritosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offer the user a JFileChooser to select the File then call Desktop.edit(File), is the easiest way to achieve that functionality.

Here it would probably load in Excel or OO.